# Change wait cursor from black and white to rainbow circle cursor in Qt on Mac(10.9)

Tags: qt, cursor

I have one question but not solution.
I want to change wait cursor from black and white to rainbow circle cursor, but I don't know how. I try using `setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor)` but not. I try using `setOverrideCursor(QCursor(QPixmap("path of picture")))`, but it is bad idea. Please help me.

Please see 2 picture:

Observer(black and white cursor) :

[image]

Expected(rainbow cursor):

[image]